# Android Dependencies not resolving in groovy project

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

I have a groovy project with

`dependencies {
  compile project(':app')
}`

where app is an android project.

When I run `./gradlew dependecies`

`compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- project :app`

is all that is printed out.

Why are all the dependencies from the app project being printed out?
Is there a way to get all of the dependencies from this project and add them to this project?

Comment: check out https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem with

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':app').configurations.compile.dependencies
}
```